# SSH through public lan with same hostname

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, lan

So I got my machine say it's IP is 10.0.0.123 and my Cisco lan switch is 10.0.0.1 my public IP is 10.103.6.1. and my other network is the same but it's public IP is 10.104.6.1.

So the question is how do I ssh to 10.0.0.123 on the second network?
I feel like I need to tunnel through the second lan somehow.

Answer (score 0):

What's your gateway device?

Basically you need to setup on your 10.104.6.1 port forwarding (or triggering, there is different terminology in different vendors).
For example you setup your port 443 or 15000 (or whatever you please) to forward to your local ip 10.0.0.123 port 22.
Then on your source (which is behind 10.103.6.1) you will connect like this

```
ssh -p 443 10.104.6.1
```

-p port number you will need to match with your port forwarding rule.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without ports since I have hundreds of machines I'd like to access on the switch.

Comment: Yes, with the Site to Site VPN. In your case since subnets overlap you would need to NAT. Have a look here http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-negotiation-ike-protocols/14143-same-ip.html

Comment: Brace yourself for lots of issues though, if possible to change the addressing of one of the private networks, it'll save you a lot of headaches.